# Javascript regex replacement of single character between alphanumeric strings.

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to do a string substitution/replacement via regex and I just can't figure it out.

The string is in the following format:
`http[s]://assets.example.com/images/[8 or 9 alphanumberic chars]m/[ 8 or 9 different alphanumeric chars].jpg`

The character I want to replace is the `m` in the middle of the 2 alphanumeric strings.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

`http://assets.example.com/images/11233434m/23435436.jpg` and I want to change it into `http://assets.example.com/images/11233434l/23435436.jpg`

I'm familiar with `str.replace`, I just can't come up with a regex that works, without replacing incorrect characters (like the last `m` in `example.com/`)

Comment: sigh. Yes I know its a pretty simple question for SO, but I did a pretty indepth search first, and I couldn't find anything similar. Would love to know why it deserves a downvote..

Comment: It's not that useful to future readers. Maybe if you invest in using a capturing group you can put it together. There are no advanced techniques here, since it's [[tag:javascript]].

Comment: Your question is very clearly written. I think the downvotes are for not showing your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does as you wish

- Find what: `(https?:\/\/assets\.example\.com\/images\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,9})m(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,9}\.jpg)`
- Replace with: `$1l$2`
- Try it: http://regex101.com/r/oO4sO5/4

Free spaced:

```
(http                   #Open capture, "http"
s?:\/\/                 #Optional "s", required "://"
assets\.example\.com\/images\/   #literal portion
[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,9})       #8-or-9 alpha-num chars, end capture
m                       #"m"
(\/                     #Start capture, "/"
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,9})\.jpg)   #8-or-9 alpha-num chars, ".jpg", end capture
```

---

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference.

Comment: Using `\Q \E` literal sequence would make the literal portion more readable, and +1 for Regex FAQ.

Comment: Good point, @Unihedron. regex101 doesn't seem to accept `\Q..\E`, so I'm going to leave it out. But you're right, it would make it more readable.

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work:

```
var str1 = "http://assets.example.com/images/11233434m/23435436.jpg";
var patt = /(http:\/\/assets\.example\.com\/images\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,9})m(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,9}\.jpg)/;
var mats = patt.exec(str);
var str2 = mats[1]+"l"+mats[2];
```

The logic is simple. Because `[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,9}` matches eight or nine alphanumeric characters, the regular expression `patt` in my code matches a string exactly as described by you. It also **captures** the part of the string before the incorrect `m` and the part of the string after it. Then we just concatenate the first part, an `l` and the second part.

Answer (score 2):

try this to see if it is help or not

```
var url = "http://assets.example.com/images/11233434m/23435436.jpg";
url.replace(/images\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,9})(m)\//, function(total, g1, g2) {
    //console.log(total, g1, g2);
    return 'images/' + g1 + "l/";
})
```

Comment: `, g2` parameter doesn't have to be there, but eh.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that works:

```
var str = 'http://assets.example.com/images/11233434m/23435436.jpg';
var replaced = str.replace(/(https?:\/\/assets\.example\.com\/images\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,9})m(\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,9}\.jpg)/, '$1l$2')
```